# Add option to select for each line echoed in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, loops

I've checked out some of the other similar questions but they aren't doing exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm ajaxing a php page to echo the contents of a folder on my server. Right now, I have it listing the files line by line. I would simply like to take the value of each line and add it to a select box.

If I can just come up with a way in javascript to run a loop for each line found from this php page, I can add the option to the select myself. Any idea of how to accomplish this? Everything I find online is for a different scenario and I can't find anything that'll work. Thanks

Edit: This is the closest I've gotten

```
var files = msg.split(" ");
                $.each(files, function(index, value) {
                    var x = document.getElementById("Emulators");
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = files;
                    x.add(option);
                });
```

When I do that, [this is the result](https://theromdepot.com/emulators.php)

Any idea why it's the last drop down is looking like that? This is what the [php page](https://theromdepot.com/updateemulator.php?system=Acorn%20Archimedes&os=Windows) is outputting

Comment: Just for clarification, I already have a javascript string that contains each file line by line, so that's not the problem. I just need a way to cycle through them and add them 1 by 1.

Comment: Can't you use split and then add the array to your listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, seeing as you're already using JS/jQuery would be to use `$.append()` [doc](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

Either do this as part of your return or loop through the file. You shouldn't need to create the file if you add it to the `.success(data)` the function of the ajax call. Simply have the PHP file you're calling echo out what you need in a format you can interpret, eg `json_encode` your output array.

Edit adding suggestion:

THE FOLLOWING IS UNTESTED AND PURELY FOR EXAMPLE:

NB: this expects `test.php` to output the formatted data as an array parsed through `json_encode`.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php"
}).success(function(data) {
  var files = JSON.parse(data);
  $.each(files, function(index, value) {
     $('#result-div').append( value );
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.each` to iterate through the data and place the `.append` in the `.each`

Comment: I updated my post using a part of your answer. Can you check it out and see why it's outputting like that?

Comment: without your source file and/or source code there's not much, it's a guessing game.

Comment: I've linked the page it's being used on and the output of the php page above, plus the part of the script I'm using. Is that enough to determine whats going on?

Comment: Oh wait, I had to change option.text = files; to option.text = value;

Now it works perfectly except theres an extra blank line. Any idea why?

Comment: Nevermind, I know why. It's with the way I'm outputting in php. I can figure it out from here, thanks!

Comment: Probably being run too many times or something. Add a check to make sure value has content before appending.

Comment: In order to use split, I have to have a character seperating each file. Because of this, it was also counting the last character (being a blank line in this case), so all I did was after the script ran, I just removed the last line. Now it works perfectly! Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: It's a pleasure @Syllith

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to iterate through the data using the array map function to call jQuery's append function.

```js
const mySelect = $('#my-select');
const files = ['path/file1.ext', 'path/file2.ext'];

files.map(x => {
  mySelect.append( $('<option value="' + x + '">' + x + '</option>') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my-select"></select>
```

Comment: Since I already have a string that lists each filename line by line, is there an easy way to convert those lines to an array? This will work for me if I can do that

Comment: Use the split function